# Longtable - Need the cell's width but multicolumns resets \hspace and \linewidth. How can I do?

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, linewidth

After hours of investigations, I could narrow-down an issue I have with tables to `\multicolumn` and what it does with `\hspace` and `\linewidth`.

As one can see in the MWE below, in a normal cell, both `\hspace` and `\linewidth` give the width of the cell (I can handle `\tabcolsep` and `arrayrulesep` if needed). I would use this width to put a minipage or something like that in the cell.

The problem is that `\multicolumn` resets those two dimensions to the whole text width.

**In any case, is there a way to retrieve the correct value ?**

NB 1: `array` or `booktabs` packages are not of any help regarding to this issue.

**[edit]**
It seemed to me like a bug but as @david-carisle pointed-out in a comment, the multicolumn is a `l` column, then a `\mbox`, not a `\parbox`, so no local `\linewidth`.

The whole use case involves a document generated  via Pandoc and a custom Lua filter, so I'll stick to a `longtable` environment. I understand that I could do some calculation in the filter but the real use case is much more complex than this MWE. It would make the lua filter quite complex.

I also edited the MWE so the table is not too wide.
**[/edit]**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright\fill
linewidth=\the\linewidth
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[]{
  p{\columnwidth) / 4}
  p{\columnwidth) / 4}
  p{\columnwidth) / 9}
  p{\columnwidth) / 4}}
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
\hline
linewidth=\the\linewidth & \multicolumn{2}{l}{linewidth=\the\linewidth}& linewidth=\the\linewidth \\
hsize=\the\hsize & \multicolumn{2}{l}{hsize=\the\hsize}& hsize=\the\hsize \\
textwidth=\the\textwidth & \multicolumn{2}{l}{textwidth=\the\textwidth}& textwidth=\the\textwidth \\
columnwidth=\the\columnwidth & \multicolumn{2}{l}{columnwidth=\the\columnwidth}& columnwidth=\the\columnwidth \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a p column is a parbox so has a local `\linewidth` and `\hsize`,  an `l` column is an `\mbox` so does not.  But you know how wide it is as it spans two `p` so it is 2*(\colunwidth/4) + 2\tabcolsep.  Your whole table is too wide as you have 4 columns of `\columnwidth/4` each with `\tabcolsep` each side, so 8\tabcolsep wider than the page (48pt by default)

Comment: Any news? You receive three answers, does any of them fulfill your expectation, consider to accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer). As I see, so far you not accept any answer on your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no auto-magic solution to keep `\linewidth` or `\hsize` equal to the cell's usable width in a multicolumn cell.
So the answer would be to use a "p column" and do the calculation myself.

Coincidentally Pandoc just switched to p columns when generating multicolumn cells in LaTeX tables.

My MWE would be :

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright\fill
linewidth=\the\linewidth
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[]{
  p{\columnwidth / 4}
  p{\columnwidth / 4}
  p{\columnwidth / 9}
  p{\columnwidth / 4}}
\hline
A & B & C & D \\
\hline
linewidth=\the\linewidth & \multicolumn{2}{p{13\columnwidth / 36 +2\tabcolsep}}{linewidth=\the\linewidth}& linewidth=\the\linewidth \\
hsize=\the\hsize & \multicolumn{2}{p{13\columnwidth / 36 +2\tabcolsep}}{hsize=\the\hsize}& hsize=\the\hsize \\
textwidth=\the\textwidth & \multicolumn{2}{p{13\columnwidth / 36 +2\tabcolsep}}{textwidth=\the\textwidth}& textwidth=\the\textwidth \\
columnwidth=\the\columnwidth & \multicolumn{2}{p{13\columnwidth / 36 +2\tabcolsep }}{columnwidth=\the\columnwidth}& columnwidth=\the\columnwidth \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I take it that your goal is to set the overall width of the `longtable` environment equal to `\textwidth`. (Aside: Since you're creating a single-column document, `\textwidth=\columnwidth`.) If that's the case, you're making a mistake right away by setting the *usable* width of each of the four columns to `\textwidth/4`.  This results in the longtable's overall width exceeding `\textwidth` by `8\tabcolsep`; if `\tabcolsep=6pt` (the default for the `article` document class), the exceedance equals `8\tabcolsep=48pt\approx 0.664in=16.9mm`.

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, you could fix the calculation by setting the usable column width to `\textwidth/4-2\tabcolsep` and thus write `\begin{longtable}{ *{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth/4-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}`. Alternatively, you could switch from a `longtable` to an [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) framework and write `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ XXXX }`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suspend full justfication
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ LLLL }
\toprule
\lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[2][1-3] & \lipsum[3][1-4] & \lipsum[4][1-4] \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems (if I understood your problem correctly}, that `longtable` is not right tool for what you like to get. Instead it try to use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package and use `X` column types:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\begin{longtblr}{colspec = {X[l] X[l] X[0.444, l] X[l]},
                 cell{2-Z}{2} = {c=2}{},
                 hspan=minimal}
    \hline
A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
linewidth=\the\linewidth 
    & linewidth=\the\linewidth
        &   & linewidth=\the\linewidth      \\
hsize=\the\hsize 
    & hsize=\the\hsize
        &   & hsize=\the\hsize              \\
textwidth=\the\textwidth 
    & textwidth=\the\textwidth
        &   & textwidth=\the\textwidth      \\
columnwidth=\the\columnwidth 
    & columnwidth=\the\columnwidth 
        &   & columnwidth=\the\columnwidth  \\
    \hline
\lipsum[2][1-2]
    & \lipsum[2][1-2]
        &   & \lipsum[2][1-2]                 \\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]